# How to return an object from a class constructor with builder pattern?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I'm trying to implement a builder pattern in javascript. I have a class `Director` that can build different animals.

The animal is created in a class called `AnimalBuilder`. The idea is to get a collection of methods to instantiate many different keys in an object which will be very different based on the animal.

It almost works. The constructor of the AnimalBuilder class is properly updated, but I can't access this simple object so far. All I receive is a constructor object.

```js
class AnimalBuilder {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  setSpecy(specy) {
    this.specy = specy;
    return this;
  }

  setIsComestible(isComestible) {
    this.isComestible = isComestible;
    return this;
  }

  create() {
    return this;
  }
}

class Director {
  buildCat(builder) {
    return builder
      .setSpecy("cat")
      .setIsComestible(false)
      .create();
  }

  buildCow(builder) {
    return builder
       .setSpecy("cow")
       .setIsComestible(true)
       .create();
  }
}

const director = new Director();
const animalBuilder = new AnimalBuilder("Jenny");
const  cow = director.buildCow(animalBuilder);
console.log(cow);

// output: AnimalBuilder {
//    name: "Jenny",
 //   specy: "cow",
 //   isComestible: true
// }
```

How to only receive:

```js
{
 name: "Jenny",
 specy: "cow",
 isComestible: true
 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want to receive the `animalBuilder` back, you need to create a new object, e.g. `return {name: this.name, species: this.specy, comestible: this.isComestible}` - i.e. doing the actual building.

Comment: What if I don't use all the methods from the class? For example, I could decide not to use isComestible() for a bird. It would create an issue because I couldn't write "isComestible: this.isComestible" without getting an error.

Comment: you wouldn't get an error, the value of this.isComestible would return undefined.

Comment: @DoneDeal0 Well what do you want to happen? What is the goal of the builder? Usually this pattern is used precisely to allow the flexibility of providing partial values, or providing them in different ways, so that the builder can handle fallbacks or validation. A builder that only collects, and does nothing else, is a bit useless - you might just create the result object directly.